# Refresh DataGridView in Windows form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two forms let it be Form A and Form B. When I click save button on Form B I want the **DataGridView** of Form A to refresh.

How i can do that?
I really need help, someone can help me?

I insert the data trought this code:

```
 provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\311026\Desktop\PAP2\Biblio.accdb"
    connString = provider
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Insert into Livrosescola([NomeLivro], [AutorLivro], [EditoraLivro], [AnoLivro]) Values (?,?,?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("NomeLivro", CType(NomeLivroTextBox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AutorLivro", CType(AutorLivroTextBox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("EditoraLivro", CType(EditoraLivroTextBox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AnoLivro", CType(AnoLivroTextBox.Text, String)))


    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        NomeLivroTextBox.Clear()
        AutorLivroTextBox.Clear()
        EditoraLivroTextBox.Clear()
        AnoLivroTextBox.Clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Thank you!!

Comment: So many, many details we dont know, like how the data got there.  You could bind them to the same `DataView` *et voila* they show the same info.  See: [Ask]

Comment: That edit doesnt show how the data gets into the DGVs, but `CType(xxxTextBox.Text, String)` is pointless because the text property is a string.  If the DGVs use the same `DataSource` you wont have to do anything at all

Comment: @Plutonix Hello Plutonix. Im using the wizard from the visual studio to data get into dgvs!!

Comment: One suggestion, load data into a DataTable with a BindingSource then the BindingSource is used as the DataGridView.DataSource. To edit a row in the DataGridView data bind to fields of the current row, the edit form the parent form check the DialogResult of the child form, if ok update the database and if successful update the DataTable. Done this way for add/edit/delete there is no need to refresh the DataGridView on the parent form. My example https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!554&authkey=!AMKbiPgm210Sm8Y&ithint=file%2czip